# Remove parentheses from the URLs query string in rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to clean up the URL's by removing parentheses from all query strings.

I tried the following code, but couldn't get it to work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [\(\)]+
RewriteRule ^(.*)[\(]+([^\)]*)[\)]+(.*)$ /$1$2$3 [R=301,L]
```

Here's an example of a URL:

```
http://www.example.com/blog/abc-post/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogname+(Blog+Name+New+York)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to match the query string you need to check the `QUERY_STRING` server variable in a `RewriteCond` directive.

Here are some ways of doing this:

### 1. Any number of parentheses - multiple redirects

For example, to remove any number of opening/closing parentheses in the query string part of the URL:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)[()]+(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1%2 [R,NE,L]
```

The `NE` flag is required in your example to avoid the %-encoded character (ie. `%3A`) being doubly encoded.

This will, however, result in multiple redirects, depending on the number of "groups" of parentheses. In your example, this will result in two redirects, because there a two "groups" of parentheses (a single parenthesis in each "group").

### 2. Any number of parentheses *pairs* - multiple (but fewer) redirects

If the parenthesis are always in matching pairs, then you can specifically check for the opening/closing parenthesis and potentially reduce the number of redirects.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)\((.*)\)(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1%2%3 [R,NE,L]
```

In your example, this results in a single redirect because there is just a single pair of parentheses. But `/abc?foo=(bar)&one=(two)` would result in two redirects.

### 3. Any number of parentheses - single redirect

This method performs multiple *internal rewrites* to remove the parentheses, followed by a single redirect once all the parentheses have been replaced:

```
# Remove parentheses from query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)[()]+(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1%2 [E=REPLACED_PARENS:1,NE,L]

# Redirect to "clean" URL
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_REPLACED_PARENS} 1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.*)\?
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,NE,L]
```

The first rule internally rewrites the request and sets an environment variable if a replacement is required.

The second rule checks for this environment variable (note that `REPLACED_PARENS` becomes `REDIRECT_REPLACED_PARENS` *after* the first rewrite) and ultimately redirects to the cleaned URL. The URL-path is grabbed from the initial request (contained in the `THE_REQUEST` server variable) to avoid inadvertantly redirecting to the directory index (eg. `index.php`) when a bare directory is requested (or front-controller is used).